# how does Haskell know `xs` is a list in the function definition?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In [book.realworldhaskell.org](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/types-and-functions.html), types and functions part under *Conditional evaluation* section, it is given the following example:

```
 -- file: ch02/myDrop.hs
 myDrop n xs = if n <= 0 || null xs
               then xs
               else myDrop (n - 1) (tail xs)
```

I did understand the implementation of the function, but my question is that how does Haskell know `xs` is a **list** ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Type inference

You write:

```
myDrop n xs = if n <= 0 || null xs
              then xs
              else myDrop (n - 1) (tail xs)
```

So Haskell first assumes that the function has type `myDrop :: a -> (b -> c)` (it first does not make any assumptions regarding the types). So in memory we store:

```
myDrop :: a -> b -> c
n :: a
xs :: b
```

But now it will start deriving types.

We see for instance `n <= 0`. Now the function `(<=)` has signature `(<=) :: Ord d => d -> d -> Bool`. So that means that `0 :: d`, and we now that for number *literals*, it holds that `0 :: Num e => e`. So we can add `Num a` to the type constraint.

We also see `null xs`, `null` has signature `null :: [f] -> Bool`, so that means that `a ~ [f]` (here `~` means type equality). We also have to check that the expression `n <= 0 || null xs` results in a `Bool` (since it is the condition of the `if`-`then`-`else`. Since `(||)` has as type `(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`, it means that `n <= 0` and `null xs` should return `Bool`s. This holds: since `(<=)` has type `Ord d -> d -> Bool`, and `null :: [f] -> Bool`. So after type inference of the first line, we have:

```
myDrop :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [f] -> c
n :: (Num a, Ord a) => a
xs :: [f]
```

Now we still need to typecheck the second and third line. In an `if`-`then`-`else` clause, the `then` expression, and `else` expression need to have the same type, so we now that the type of `xs` is the same as `myDrop (n-1) (tail xs)`. So even without knowing the signature of `myDrop (n-1) (tail xs)` we know already that it needs to have type `myDrop :: g -> h -> [f]` (here we currently do not know the type of `g` and `h`.

Since we are deriving the type of `myDrop`, we can check the type we have constructed thus far, with the one we are calling, so we compare it like:

```
myDrop :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [f] -> c  -- currently derived
myDrop ::                   g -> h   -> [f] -- called
```

So we derive that: `a ~ g`, and `c ~ h ~ [f]`. So now we know that `myDrop` has type:

```
myDrop :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [f] -> [f]
```

We now still need to typecheck the arguments. We see for instance that the first argument in the call is `n - 1`, the signature of `(-)` is `(-) :: Num i => i -> i -> i`, and `1` is a number literal, so `1 :: Num j => j`, so we derive that in this specific context `i ~ j ~ a`, and as a result `n - 1 :: a`, thus holds with the derived type for the function.

We also know that `tail` has signature `tail :: [k] -> [k]`. Since we call it with `xs :: [f]`, we know that `f ~ k`, and thus `tail xs :: [f]`, this again holds. We did not had to derive `a` or `f`, further, so we can set the type as:

```
myDrop n xs :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [f] -> [f]
```

## Improving the function

The above function works, and it will work regardless what input we provide. But I would call it a bit "unsafe" in the sense that it works because we work with contracts the function we call (`tail` and `null`). For example `tail` will error in case we provide it an empty list. Yes, this can never happen, since `null` checks this. But we thus have to reason about that ourselves. It is usually better to work only with *total* functions: functions that *always* return valid output.

We can here perform pattern matching in the head of the function. A Haskell compiler can derive that we are missing patterns, so if we turn on that feature, then we can validate that all the cases are covered.

We can write it as:

```
myDrop :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [f] -> [f]
myDrop _ [] = []
myDrop n xa@(_:xs) | n <= 0 = xa
                   | otherwise = myDrop (n-1) xs
```

So here the first line convers the case where the list is empty (regardless what `n` is, we return an empty list). In case the list is not empty, it has as pattern `(_:xs)` (and we also keep a reference to `xa`, the entire list. In case `n <= 0`, we return `xa`, otherwise we decrement `n`, and make a recursive call on the tail.

Answer (score 8):

You are calling `null` and `tail` on `xs`.

```
null :: [a] -> Bool
tail :: [a] -> [a]
```

The arguments to both are lists, so Haskell can infer that, if you are calling `null xs` or `tail xs`, the type of `xs` must be `[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. Haskell doesn't know that `xs` is a list until it tries to compile the invocation.

When you call `myDrop 3 someList` Haskell knows that `null someList` can accept `someList`, and that `tail someList` can be called on `someList` and returns a list. Haskell's (magical) type system can infer (at compile time) how to compile `myDrop n xs` with what it already knows.

In theory, if you made some "not-list" things that worked for `tail` and `null` you could call `myDrop 3 notList` and get sensible results.

Comment: There are some problems with this answer: (a) Haskell's type system is *not* lazy, (b) `null` returns a `Bool`, not a list, (c) it does not find these things out at runtime (there are languages that do that, for instance there are Prolog environments that perform abstract compilation). Otherwise I could have constructed a program where I wrote `foo = myDrop 3 1`, and the compiler would only error in case I indeed called `foo`, but the compiler will proactively error.

Comment: It's still wrong. Haskell absolutely does know that `xs` is a list, even if `myDrop` is never used.